# CSS not loading in Facebook canvas page

Tags: css, facebook, codeigniter, canvas

I have an application built with CodeIgniter that I have deployed as an app on Facebook. 
I did this by adding it as a Canvas Page, so that it can be accessed at apps.facebook.com/myapp.

It loads up fine in the canvas, but none of my app's css is loaded. The page is without styling. Also none of my links seem to work.

Is this because of the base_url(); that I used throughout by app to link styelsheets and navigation?

Not sure what to do.

When I go directly to the app via the web address, which is the canvas url, it loads up and looks fine and as it should.

Comment: Is your base URL using HTTP as protocol? Then browsers will block loading of any external resources when the page is loaded into the FB iframe via HTTPS.

Comment: Yes I was using http, as per the answer below I changed my base url in my config.php file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be your base_url(); set in Codeigniter since as you said it is used through the app to link everything.

When setting up the canvas in the dashboard you should have entered, and would have been required to enter a secure canvas url. This is the same as the canvas url except with https.

Change your base_url() in you config.php file to https and reload the canvas. This would have to change to the secure canvas url because you use the app as a logged in Facebook user. This si why the secure canvas url is required when setting up.

Let me know.